# Spring Application Properties from Dependency

Tags: java, spring, gradle

Suppose we have a Spring application (say using Gradle or Maven).

We control a Maven dependency which imports various spring boot starters and configures them (using `@Configuration` and `application*.yml` files).

When does the imported configuration apply? If the application defines its own application.yml, what are the rules for determining which configuration “wins” over the over?

Comment: Only 1 applicaiton.properties/yaml/xml will be loaded, the first on the classpath which is generally the on from your own application **not** the one fromt he dependencies.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I'm pretty sure there's a way to request a loading of several `ApplicationContext`s, and then each one of those can load its own properties file. But yes, by default it loads just the one it discovers first.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for your quick response! What is the preferred way of "importing" configuration? In my case, I have various microservices that I want to configure in a single place? Should I only be using `@Configuration`?

Comment: Use a config server for that.